# RewriteRule to access folder outside public folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file is redirecting requests to the public_html folder.

For example, `http://mydomain.com/file.html` would show `root_folder/public_html/file.html`.

However, I would like it to show `root_folder/anotherfolder/file.html` instead.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: @Prix isn't there a way to redirect files *internally* beyond the public_html folder?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
Alias /file.html root_folder/anotherfolder/file.html
```